# Разбор цветов объекта на изображении

Tags: c#

В общем, хочу написать программу которая будет определять c фото сопротивление резистора по его цветовой маркировки. В какую сторону копать? Даже не знаю что вводить в гугле

Comment: [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы знаете где на фотографии начинается и заканчивается объект, то просто получите битмап этой области и посмотрите какие цвета встречаются и в каком порядке.

Comment: Но надо ещё найти этот объект

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно гуглить по теме распознавания изображений и OpenCV.